# Blocking for 0.04 seconds when SO_SNDBUF is small

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel

I'm playing with small SO_SNDBUF values, mainly to test my own buffering code.

I've set it to 1024 (though when I read it back it's 4608). I use edge triggered epoll to be notified when it can be written to. The following is from my "flush buffer" function.

```
    int sent = 0;
send:;
    int n = write(sock, outBuf+sent, outLength-sent);
    if (n == -1) {
        if (likely(errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
            c->writable = false;
            return;
        }
        c->valid = false;
        return;
    }
    sent += n;
    if (n && outLength-sent)
        goto send;
    c->writable = sent == outLength;
    return;
```

With a larger buffer this seems to perform correctly. However, with SO_SNDBUF of 4608, it blocks very quickly, and then can't be written to for about 0.04 seconds.

Meanwhile the system is 99% idle.

Where does this delay of 0.04 seconds come from? I had a grep through the kernel and all I could find was TCP_DELACK_MIN and TCP_ATO_MIN (both set to HZ/25), though I don't think they're the cause?

Is my code correct? Do I need the `goto`, given answer 9 on [man 7 epoll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html)?

In case it makes a difference, I'm using TCP_NODELAY, and the client and server are on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the fact that the buffer is full and hasn't been written to the network and acknowledged by the peer yet.

Comment: Both client and server are running on the same machine. CPU usage is ~1%, ruling out overhead. The 0.04 seconds must come from somewhere, I'm interested to find out where.